# Closing - "my brand new bike has a fault" warranty questions

Tags: discussion

We occasionally get questions where someone has a brand new bike and there's something wrong with it.  Example  [Hydraulic disc brakes](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/58120/hydraulic-disc-brakes)

The fault is often something trivial like poor shifting or brakes not bedded in and we generally have a pre-existing question with answers.

But these are brand new bikes, presumably with some sort of warranty from the shop.

**Question** should they be

- closed as duplicates of the existing task (enabling people to void their warranty?)
- closed as off topic (well they're 100% about bikes so no)
- closed as a dupe of a canonical question which discusses warranties in different countries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thee question are really no different than any other question where the OP is seeking information why something is wrong with their bike and how to fix it

They should just be answered, with recommendation to take the bike to the point of sale to get it fixed.

If there is an existing question for whatever the problem is, we can close as usual and leave a comment to take the bike to the point of sale.